# Sort results by relevance with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, text

I have a search engine that, depending on what the users inputs, displays elements in an array in order of viewCount, uploadDate, and rating, but relevance is kicking my butt; I have no clue where to start.

First, data is retrieved from multiple xml/json feeds.

```
 $url1 = "http://api.site1.com/?q=$userinput";
 $url2 = "http://api.site2.com/?q=$userinput";
 $url3 = "http://api.site3.com/?q=$userinput";

 //get_and_decode is a function that gets and decodes data from the xml/json feed
 get_and_decode($url1);
 get_and_decode($url2);
 get_and_decode($url3);
```

Second, all the data is stored in an array.

Finally, the elements in the array are displayed for the user and sorted by either view count, upload date, or rating.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I am trying to learn how to calculate relevance.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific

Comment: Do you mind sharing a sample array?

Comment: Please provide example code with sample data (show us what the data in your array looks like), so we can help you better. What data type is `relevance`?

Comment: Sure: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: If you're trying to sort by a pre-existing relevance field, please elaborate on your question a bit more. If you need help figuring out how to calculate relevance, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ may be a better fit for this question, as one of its specialties is algorithms. (See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not related to a specific programming language, but more precisely of the algorithm used. First, try to determine a good algorithm to express relevance as a number. For example, you can try to start from [ranking](http://www.lextek.com/manuals/onix/ranking.html) or [relevancy](http://www.google.com/enterprise/relevancy.html).